# convert react class to react hooks useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-grid-layout

Can someone help me convert this to react hooks I believe  it would be react useState()

https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/7-localstorage.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import RGL, { WidthProvider } from "react-grid-layout";

const ReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(RGL);
const originalLayout = getFromLS("layout") || [];
/**
 * This layout demonstrates how to sync to localstorage.
 */
 export default class LocalStorageLayout extends React.PureComponent {
 static defaultProps = {
 className: "layout",
 cols: 12,
 rowHeight: 30,
 onLayoutChange: function() {}
};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      layout: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalLayout))
    };

    this.onLayoutChange = this.onLayoutChange.bind(this);
    this.resetLayout = this.resetLayout.bind(this);
  }

  resetLayout() {
    this.setState({
      layout: []
    });
  }

  onLayoutChange(layout) {
    /*eslint no-console: 0*/
    saveToLS("layout", layout);
    this.setState({ layout });
    this.props.onLayoutChange(layout); // updates status display
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.resetLayout}>Reset Layout</button>
        <ReactGridLayout
          {...this.props}
          layout={this.state.layout}
          onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}
        >
          <div key="2" data-grid={{ w: 2, h: 3, x: 8, y: 0 }}>
            <span className="text">5</span>
          </div>
        </ReactGridLayout>
      </div>
    );
   }
}

function getFromLS(key) {
  let ls = {};
   if (global.localStorage) {
    try {
      ls = JSON.parse(global.localStorage.getItem("rgl-7")) || {};
    } catch (e) {
      /*Ignore*/
    }
  }
  return ls[key];
 }

 function saveToLS(key, value) {
  if (global.localStorage) {
   global.localStorage.setItem(
    "rgl-7",
      JSON.stringify({
      [key]: value
    })
  );
 }
}

 if (process.env.STATIC_EXAMPLES === true) {
 import("../test-hook.jsx").then(fn => fn.default(LocalStorageLayout));
}
```

trying my best to understand react classes since I only know react hooks so any patince help would be so amazing and helpful please and thank you

Answer (score 0):

React classes are simple if you understand the lifecycle of a component.
A component is instantiated, then mounted (associated with DOM) & then it renders.
After every update (state or props) it's re-rendered.

**Constructor**
The instantiation of a component or any JS class happens in the `constructor`.  It is run only **once**.
Since class components inherit from `React.Component`, they pass the props to `React.Component` by calling `super(props)`. This initializes the `props` field.
`super` calls should be the 1st line in a constructor.
You **cannot** access the following in the constructor: `window`, `document`, `fetch`, `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`.

**render**
The render method returns the rendered `Element`/`Fragment`. It corresponds to the returned part of a function component. It runs every time the component is rendered.

**Event listener binding**
The hardest part of classes is the event method binding.
The implicit `this` object, is necessary to access state, props & other component methods. However, inside an *event listener method**. it refers to the **event target**.  Hence the `bind` calls. Nevertheless, this problem, can be bypassed by using **arrow methods** as the arrow functions do not have their *own* `this` (ie. `this` does not refer to event target).
Function components don't have this problem, as they don't need `this`.

**State**
The state is initialized in the constructor.
Unlike function components, classes treat the state as a **single object**.
Instead of,

```
let [x, setX] = useState(0); let [y, setY] = useState(1);
```

In classes it's:

```
this.state = {x:0, y:1};
```

And to update state, we use the `setState` method,

```
this.setState({x: 3}); // updates only x, & y is unchanged: setX(3)
this.setState({x: 3, y: 4}); // updates both x & y: setX(3); setY(4)
this.setState((state)=>({ y: state.y - 1)) // updates y using previous value: setY(y=>y-1)
```

An advantage of classes is that we can update a state property using *another* state property's *previous* value.

```
this.setState((state)=>({x: (y%2)? 100: 50})); // updates x using y's value
```

Also, the state can be updated with respect to props:

```
this.setState((state,props)=>({x: state.x + props.dx}));
```

In addition, `setState` has an optional **2nd callback argument**.  This callback is run immediately **after** the state update.

```
this.setState(state=>({x: state.x+1}), ()=> {
    // called after x is updated
    sessionStorage.setItem('x', this.state.x);
});

// function version
setX(x=>x+1);

useEffect(()=> {
    localStorage.setItem('x', x);
}, [x]); // runs every time x is updated
```

**Mounting**
After mounting, `componentDidMount()` is called. Now, component can access the `window` & `document` objects.
Here here, you can

- Call `setInterval`/`setTimeout`
- Update state with API calls (`fetch`) or storage (`localStorage` & `sessionStorage`)

It's equivalent to `useEffect(()=> {}, [])`

**Unmounting**

Before unmounting `componentWillUnmount()` is called. Typically, `clearTimeout`/`clearInterval` are called here to *clean* up the component.

It's equivalent to the returned method of `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    //....
    return ()=> {
        // componentWillUnmount code
    };
}, [])
```